# How to get NSData from image picker?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-story

I try to share video to instagram stories from selected video from my photo library

```
func shareToInstagramStories(video: NSData) {
            // NOTE: you need a different custom URL scheme for Stories, instagram-stories, add it to your Info.plist!
            guard let instagramUrl = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share") else {
                return
            }

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramUrl) {
                let pasterboardItems = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundVideo": video as Any]]
                UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasterboardItems)
                UIApplication.shared.open(instagramUrl)
            } else {
                //fail
            }
    }
```

here is the my image picker function

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.init(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")] as? NSURL
     }
```

Comment: referenceURL is deprecated. Btw for iOS 14 or later you should use PHPickerViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change the "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" to "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL" its totally worked

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.init(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL")] as? URL
 }
```